# SQL getting number of records inserted in each hour of past 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to write a SQL query where I need to get the number of records inserted in **each hour** of **last 24 hours**. Somewhere I stumbled upon this Query:

```
SELECT HOUR(timeStamp), COUNT(*)
FROM `events`
WHERE timeStamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(timeStamp)
ORDER BY HOUR(timeStamp)
```

The original table:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| eventID | personID | eventName | eventContent | timeStamp           | dateModified           |
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+------------------------+
|       1 |        4 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:43:24 | 2019-12-26 12:13:23 pm |
|       2 |        1 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:43:39 | 2019-12-26 12:13:38 pm |
|       3 |        1 | Button    | Click        | 26-12-2019 17:43:40 | 2019-12-26 12:13:38 pm |
|       4 |        1 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:43:56 | 2019-12-26 12:13:55 pm |
|       5 |        1 | Mouse     | Moved        | 26-12-2019 17:43:57 | 2019-12-26 12:13:56 pm |
|       6 |        4 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:44:18 | 2019-12-26 12:14:18 pm |
|       7 |        4 | Logged Out| Logged Out   | 26-12-2019 17:44:20 | 2019-12-26 12:14:19 pm |
|       8 |        5 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:49:42 | 2019-12-26 12:19:41 pm |
|       9 |        5 | Message   | Hello        | 26-12-2019 17:49:44 | 2019-12-26 12:19:43 pm |
|      10 |        5 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:49:57 | 2019-12-26 12:19:57 pm |
|      11 |        1 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 17:58:20 | 2019-12-26 12:28:20 pm |
|      12 |        8 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 18:6:32  | 2019-12-26 12:36:31 pm |
|      13 |       54 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 18:6:50  | 2019-12-26 12:36:49 pm |
|      14 |       29 | Login     | Login        | 26-12-2019 18:7:11  | 2019-12-26 12:37:11 pm |
|      15 |        1 | Message   | Hello        | 27-12-2019 13:51:48 | 2019-12-27 08:21:49 am |
|      16 |        1 | Login     | Login        | 27-12-2019 13:51:50 | 2019-12-27 08:21:52 am |
|      17 |        1 | Login     | Login        | 27-12-2019 13:52:26 | 2019-12-27 08:22:28 am |
|      18 |        1 | Login     | Login        | 27-12-2019 13:54:59 | 2019-12-27 08:25:00 am |
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

But the SQL gives me zero outputs:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

The output I was expecting was 24 numbers with their position indicating each hour.

For example: `12 2 4 5 14 83 23 12 2 5 7 9 56 0 1 23 54 27 45 14 0 65 23 15` (these are not the actual numbers from the table. It's the format)

Comment: In MySQL/MariaDB `HOUR()` function accepts `time` datatype argument, not datetime/timestamp. Use `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timeStamp)` instead.

Comment: Still the same result! @Akina

Comment: I would expect timestamp to be in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss how are you storing it?

Comment: @P.Salmon ```26-12-2019 17:43:24``` this is the sample of time stored

Comment: Your timestamp seems to be a string, not an actual timestamp.

Comment: The query seems to be correct , I have checked in my local db. There is an issue with your timestamp format.

Comment: Tested in MySQL just now - worked like a charm. You're doing something wrong. Most probable assumption is that your columns are strings, not real timestamps. Or maybe there are simply no records for last 24h? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp is a string to use the hour function successfully you need to convert it using str_to_date for example hour(str_to_date('26-12-2019 17:43:24','%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s'))

Comment: I changed the datatype of the timeStamp field, and also got it to store the time in appropriate format, Still the same result

Comment: Have you checked the code works using mysql only? (others have stated it does) If it does then the problem is with your php code.

Comment: Just got it checked. It works perfect on MySQL. I'll figure out what the problem is with PHP. Thanks for the help!

Comment: just found the problem. I did not select the fields as some variable with a name, so it did not return anything to PHP.